# How to create a nested polymorphic form and control the child records rendered for the parent and children

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested, polymorphism

The models I am using are Merchant, Address, Phone, & Contact. The relationsships are as follows:

Merchant:

```
has_many :phones, :as => :phoneable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :contacts, :as => :entity, :dependent => :destroy
```

Contact:

```
has_many :phones, :as => :phoneable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
```

I have a form where one can create a parent record with two address records and many phone records. My merchants controller new method has this setup code:

```
@merchant.addresses.build (:address_type => "Dba")
@merchant.addresses.build (:address_type => "Mailing")
@merchant.phones.build (:phone_type => "Business")
@merchant.phones.build (:phone_type => "Fax")
```

The actual form has;

```
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
```

for the two addresses for the merchant, and;

```
<%= f.fields_for :phones do |p| %>
```

for the merchant's phone records.

The problem I am having is when adding the contacts it's address and phone records;

```
<%= f.fields_for :contacts do |c| %>
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
<%= f.fields_for :phones do |p| %>
```

which renders two addresses and phones for each contact record.

I only want the two addresses for the merchant record. How do I get the two addresses.build & phones.build to create records only for the parent and build only one address & phone record for each contact (which will be added to the form dynamically via a link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have 'new' action on merchant display a form which displays two addresses to be filled in by the user. The submit action of this form will create the merchant. It will also have a link to 'add contacts', which will display another form for creation of contact. 'New' form for contact should display one address and one phone number to be filled in by the user.

Comment: Thanks Salil, that did the trick. Now to get dynamic adding of contact, address, & phone fields. Looking into the nested_form plugin by Ryan Bates. I tried the methods in the RailCast 197 which was not successful.